# Rails Server exiting automatically immediately after start in newly cloned github repo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have cloned a github repo and run the command bundle install, but after when I am starting the rails server it shows me the following error :

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7Tk4.png)

Comment: Take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/4630)

Comment: Please include a link to the github repo. It could be helpful to see some code. Since you are new here, please go through the guidelines at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

The Device version which you're using seems to be buggy, try to upgrade the version of Devise and see

```
gem 'devise', '~> 4.4.0'
```